# PHP Session: ID generated server side only?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Consider the following PHP script:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

When you open this page via browser, you should see the session ID **generated by the server.**
For a standard php.ini setup, this session ID might be 32 characters long ranging from 0-9 a-v (5 bits per character). Example:

```
va9o92iefqoe0ouiado99r9hr299oamc
```

Now, suppose you manually changed in the browser the cookie's session ID from `va9o92iefqoe0ouiado99r9hr299oamc` to `z`, and then accessed again the above script:

At first, I would expect that PHP should be smart enough to recognize that such session ID was not generated by the server and, therefore, it should be ignored and a new one should be generated server side. Unfortunately, this is not what happens. Actually, PHP just moves forward with `z` as session ID.

I'm not sure how a malicious user could exploit that, but I don't like the idea of session ID being generated client side.

**Question**

Am I missing something? If not, how to harden PHP session to mitigate such issue?

Comment: There's not really an exploit to be had here. PHP uses long random strings by default, in part to prevent the guessing of a session ID. If a user wants to shoot themselves in the foot by setting a session ID of `z`, that's really on them. If you *really* feel strongly about it, throw an exception if `session_id()` is less than a certain number of characters.

Comment: This is called session hijacking and one of the many reasons you should use SSL.  When you change the cookie on the client side, PHP will just issue a new session for that id with no data associated with it. If you have a security check for something in the session and not just the session itself, you are fine.

Comment: Unless you're using a very old, unsupported version of PHP there's a CSPRNG generating long session IDs, and session enumeration isn't a terribly viable attack.

Comment: @Sammitch Mind to explain how CSPRNG would avoid client side generation of SID?

Comment: If you can collide with any CSPRNG with any level of reliability you'll have intelligence agencies showing up at your door. Hopefully with bags of money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to php.ini:

```
; Whether to use strict session mode.  
; Strict session mode does not accept an uninitialized session ID, and  
; regenerates the session ID if the browser sends an uninitialized session ID.  
; Strict mode protects applications from session fixation via a session adoption  
; vulnerability. It is disabled by default for maximum compatibility, but  
; enabling it is encouraged.  
; https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_sessions  
session.use_strict_mode = 0
```

Also, available at the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> When `session.use_strict_mode` is enabled. You do not have to remove obsolete session ID cookie because session module will not accept session ID cookie when there is no data associated to the session ID and set new session ID cookie. **Enabling `session.use_strict_mode` is recommended for all sites.**

Therefore, just changing to `session.use_strict_mode = 1` is enough to avoid client side generation of session ID.

Answer (score -1):

you should call session_set_cookie_params() before session_start()

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

the last param $httponly

Comment: Mind to explain how httponly would mitigate client side generation of SID?

Comment: it is only prevent javascript to rewrite your cookie , if you want use full solution , you can use AES-256 encrypt session id